How do I open excel from access when no one is logged in
I'm using a company subscribed version of Office 365.   Using Task scheduler I run a local bat file, that starts an access program located on another networked computer.  The program checks a sub folder for the presence of an excel file.  If found it starts excel, opens the file, then reads the sheets.  Then closes the file and moves it to a different sub folder.
If I run the bat file by double clicking it, it runs successfully.  If I run the bat file in Task scheduler, with the 'run if logged in' box checked, it runs successfully.
But if I choose 'run whether some one is logged in or not' The access program starts, it successfully finds the excel file, but when it tries to open the excel application, I get an error:
Error in isExcelRunning Err:ActiveX component can't create object"
The code that is causing the error is:
`Public Sub fOpenExcel(ByRef xlApp As Object)
     Call LetErrProcName("fOpenExcel")
     Call LetErrModName("modExcelUtilities")
On Error GoTo ERR_fOpenExcel

DoEvents
If IsExcelRunning Then
     Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
Else
     Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
End If

Exit Sub

Private Function IsExcelRunning() As Boolean
     Call LetErrProcName("IsExcelRunning")
     Call LetErrModName("modExcelUtilities")
On Error GoTo ERR_IsExcelRunning

Dim xlApp As Object

Err.Clear
Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
IsExcelRunning = (Err.Number = 0)
Set xlApp = Nothing
Err.Clear

Exit Function
`

What I think is happening is, even though no one is logged in, Task scheduler is able to pass credintials to Access to open it.  But since the excel application is called from access, Excel can't open because there is no one logged in and therefore doen't have credintials to open.
In Task scheduler, I checked 'Run with Highest Privelage' and it still errors when trying to open excel.
Does anyone have any suggestions?
Thaks in advance,
Adolph

As far as I know you should be able to setup an account to use by the scheduled task?
